# update browser via asp.net from background processes trace alerts

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, trace, progress

I have a webservice method which takes an Id and then will kick off a class library to process some infomration about the Id given.

The Processor uses the Trace.Write() stuff to report progress back. This works well on a console app, but I want to be able to send the same information back to the user via the web.

What would be the best way to capture these trace events (which happen very fast, many per second) and to send them to the browser.

I could store the entire trace and send back when the process is complete, but if it could be streamed to the browser as it was happening, then it would provide user feedback as well as information about the process to the user.

This is an ASP.NET service, ashx file.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

here is my code to kick off the process:

```
function ProcessEmail(emailId) {
        var popupcontent = $("#EmailPopUp");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: "/MailboxPro/Methods/Emails.ashx?action=TestProgress",
            data: { EmailId: emailId },
            success: function (result) {
                alert("result");
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the listener still being "attached" to the output.

Calling `Listeners.Remove(myListener)` at the end of the process, meant it would work each subsequent times.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one of the way could be to hook up trace output to the response using [TraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx). There is already exists a implementation that writes trace output to the response - look at [WebPageTraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpagetracelistener.aspx). In case, output formatting by this listener is not up to your liking, you can always write your own trace listener. The important thing here would be to turn off buffering your response output (using [BufferOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.bufferoutput.aspx) property) so that your updates are send to client immediately. You also need to keep your request alive - i.e. `ProcessRequest` should not end till your process in complete. You have to fiddle with request time out setting in ASP.NET configuration based on how long your process takes.

Alternately, you may choose to return your ashx immediately and then make periodic ajax requests to get the process updates. Again, you have to capture trace output and store it in some storage (for example, memory or file) and return it when ajax request come for process update.

Comment: I am calling the method via ajax too, and the "Success" function does not appear to run until the Response has finished. Should I launch the process in a different way?

Comment: @Simon, I believe that your ashx kicks off the actual processing the request thread. You can kick it on different thread using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` - that way your ashx will return immediately. For progress update, you need to make subsequent ajax calls from java-script.

Comment: I can get it to work first time. The ASHX streams the trace response back to the browser. Any subsequent attemp will return an error saying cannot write to a completed response, but it is a new request each time, surely?

Comment: @Simon, if are writing to the response stream of ashx then you can launch the processing in different thread because you need to keep request running. If you use different thread then you have capture the trace output in say session and return it back when next ajax request is made. Note that next request would use some different semantic e.g. a query parameter to indicate that it is requesting a status update from previous request.

Comment: The process only takes 10/15 seconds, so i could just send the entire output back in one go, but a little progress update seemed useful. I just dont get why it is working the first time, but not subsequently. The polling to retrieve the result, wouldnt really work as it is such a short time to process.